# Flutter- Draw points on image use canvas

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing, canvas

I want to plot some (red color)points in the image,  my image width and height assume (300 x 300) and I plot  (red color) points in Offset(76.2, 75.2) position at image(1,1).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvGt0.jpg

In some cases I need to change the image to (450x 450), but already plot  (red color)points are a mismatch.
How to move red color points to (1,1) position of image? how to calculate Offset value.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xua9h.jpg

Comment: draw your own coordinate axes and grid lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recalcuate the offsets for the new resolution.
Simply calculate a scale factor by which you can multiply the offsets and redraw the canvas. Pseudocode:

```
offset = (76.2, 75.2)
scale = 450/300 // 1.5
newOffset = offset * scale //(114.3, 112,5)
```